# Why is my genetic mutation code not retuning the entire gene? Java

Tags: java, arraylist, genetic-programming

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOIky.png

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package parentmutation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Renter
 */
public class Parentmutation {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    static int population = 50;
    static int geneSize = 25;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] parenta = new char[geneSize];                     //Create parents to pull genes from
        for (int x = 0; x < geneSize; x++) {
            parenta[x] = 'A';
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println();
        char[] parentb = new char[geneSize];
        for (int x = 0; x < geneSize; x++) {
            parentb[x] = 'B';
        }

        char[][] people = new char[population][];                //How many children to make
        Parentmutation p = new Parentmutation();
        for (int x = 0; x < population; x++) {
            people[x] = p.flopChild(parenta, parentb);           //Save it for later
            System.out.println(people[x]);                       //Output it for now
        }




    }

    public char[] flopChild(char[] a, char[] b) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int y = 0;
        ArrayList<Integer> parts = new ArrayList();
        char[] child = new char[geneSize];

        while (y < geneSize) {                                  //Break it into parts so you can easily swap genes from the parents
            int num = r.nextInt(geneSize + 1 - y);
            if (num + y > geneSize) {
                parts.add(num + y - geneSize);
                y = geneSize + 1;
            } else {
                if (num == 0) {
                } else {
                    parts.add(num);
                    y += num;
                }
            }
        }

        int last = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < parts.size(); x++) {                //Use the pieces to get chunks from the parents var a and b
            for (int z = last; z < last + parts.get(x); z++) {
                if (r.nextInt(2) == 0) {                        //Decied which parent to pull from
                    child[z] = a[z];
                } else {
                    child[z] = b[z];
                }
            }
            last = parts.get(x);
        }
        return child;
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to create some children based off two parents. The goal is to take parent a with traits "AAAAA" and parent b with traits "BBBBB" and randomly give them to children. Results would look like "ABABA", "AAAAB", or any other combination of those. The code I have now swaps the traits and returns them for the child however they are not always the correct length. The code I included only runs through it once to simplify things. Here are some example results.

```
    run:

    -------------------------

    ABBBBABBBBABAABABBBAAAB
    BBAAAAABABBBBABAAAAAA
    BAAAAAABABBBB
    BAAAABBAABBABABAABBABABBB
    BBAAAAABBABBABAABBA
    BAABBAAABBAABBBAAAABAAAB
    BBABABAABABAABBBBBAAAA
    BBBBABAAAABBBBBAABBAA
    ABAABBABBBBBAAABABBABAAB
```

Comment: Please add your code here and explain what is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected version of the `flopChild` method.

```
public static char[] flopChild(final char[] a, final char[] b) {
    final Random r = new Random();
    int y = 0;
    final ArrayList<Integer> parts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    final char[] child = new char[geneSize];

    while (y < geneSize) { // Break it into parts so you can easily swap
                            // genes from the parents
        final int num = r.nextInt(geneSize + 1 - y);
        if (num + y > geneSize) {
            parts.add(num + y - geneSize);
            y = geneSize + 1;
        } else {
            if (num == 0) {
            } else {
                parts.add(num);
                y += num;
            }
        }
    }

    int last = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < parts.size(); x++) { // Use the pieces to get chunks
                                                // from the parents var a
                                                // and b
        final int next = last + parts.get(x);
        final char[] parent = r.nextInt(2) == 0 ? a : b; /*
                                                         * You want the same
                                                         * parent for one
                                                         * given chunk,
                                                         * right?
                                                         */
        for (int z = last; z < next; z++) {
            child[z] = parent[z];
        }
        last = next; // And not parts.get(x)
    }
    return child;
}
```

I corrected two things:

- The `last` variable was assigned to `parts.get(x)` (a random place in the array) instead of `last + parts.get(x)`. That caused your length issue.
- You do a lot of work to process the arrays by chunks, but then you choose the parent at random for each element instead of each chunk.

The output now looks like:

```
-------------------------
ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBAAA
AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAABB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAB
BBBBBBBBAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAABBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBABBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAABB
BBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAABAAAAAAABBBBBAAB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAB
BBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBAAAB
ABBBBBBBAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAB
AAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBABAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBA
BBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
AAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBAAABBB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBAAAA
```

Comment: You said you corrected "You do a lot of work to process the arrays by chunks, but then you choose the parent at random for each element instead of each chunk.". What exactly do you mean by this. I dont really see too much of a difference except formatting.

Comment: You said "You do alot of work to process the arrays by chunks". How would you have approached it?

Comment: @user1832787 with your original code, you choose one parent at random for each char, which make your chunks useless. I moved the parent choice outside the for loop, so that the same parent is used for one chunk (I guess it's what you want). Move the parent choice inside the loop again and you'll see the result in the output.